ShellSpec :Error in 'before and after all hook' terminates test execution even the status code is 0
I have a test function which setup my environment before the tests execute.
Setup environment before all tests
setup_environment() {
    set -x # Enable verbose output

    # Determine the OS type
    OS_TYPE=$(uname 2>/dev/null || echo "Unknown")

    case "$OS_TYPE" in
        Darwin|Linux)
            TMP_DIR="/tmp"
            ;;
        CYGWIN*|MINGW*|MSYS*)
            # Ensure cygpath is available before using it
            if command -v cygpath >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                TMP_DIR="$(cygpath -m "${TEMP:-/tmp}")"
            else
                echo "Error: cygpath not found. Is Cygwin or Git Bash installed?" >&2
                return 1
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Error: Unsupported OS: $OS_TYPE" >&2
            return 1
            ;;
    esac

    # Use a unique directory for each test run to avoid conflicts
    TEST_ID=$(date +%s)
    export EXTRACT_DELTA_CONSOLE_LOG_PATH="$TMP_DIR/extract-delta-console-log-$TEST_ID"
    export MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_ROOT="$TMP_DIR/minimized-checkout-root-$TEST_ID"
    export CHECKOUT_ROOT="$TMP_DIR/checkout-root-$TEST_ID"
    export EXTRACTED_DELTA_ROOT="$TMP_DIR/extracted-delta-root-$TEST_ID"

    # Clean up any pre-existing directories
    rm -rf "$EXTRACT_DELTA_CONSOLE_LOG_PATH" "$MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_ROOT" "$CHECKOUT_ROOT" "$EXTRACTED_DELTA_ROOT"

    # Create necessary directories and handle errors
    mkdir -p "$EXTRACT_DELTA_CONSOLE_LOG_PATH" || {
        echo "Failed to create log dir at $EXTRACT_DELTA_CONSOLE_LOG_PATH"
        return 1
    }
    mkdir -p "$MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_ROOT" || {
        echo "Failed to create checkout dir at $MINIMIZED_CHECKOUT_ROOT"
        return 1
    }
    mkdir -p "$CHECKOUT_ROOT" || {
        echo "Failed to create root checkout dir at $CHECKOUT_ROOT"
        return 1
    }
    mkdir -p "$EXTRACTED_DELTA_ROOT" || {
        echo "Failed to create extracted delta dir at $EXTRACTED_DELTA_ROOT"
        return 1
    }

    # Git operations
    mkdir -p "$CHECKOUT_ROOT/default-branch"
    cd "$CHECKOUT_ROOT/default-branch" || {
        echo "Failed to change directory to $CHECKOUT_ROOT/default-branch"
        return 1
    }

    git init || {
        echo "Failed to initialize Git"
        return 1
    }
    git config core.autocrlf false || {
        echo "Failed to set Git config"
        return 1
    }

    # Create and commit an initial file
    echo "Initial file content" >file1.txt
    git add file1.txt || {
        echo "Failed to add file1.txt"
        return 1
    }
    git commit -m "Initial commit" || {
        echo "Failed to commit"
        return 1
    }

    # Checkout the main branch
    git checkout -b main || {
        echo "Failed to checkout branch 'main'"
        return 1
    }
    echo "Setup completed for test: $TEST_ID"
}

Once executed, this fails by given the following error

a) ERROR: An error occurred in before all hook 'setup_environment || fail "Setup failed, terminating"' (exit status: 0)

Similar error is given in the after all function as well.
b) ERROR: An error occurred in after hook 'teardown_environment || fail "Teardown failed"' (exit status: 0)
   + eval 'set -- "$1" "${SHELLSPEC_AFTER_ALL_1#*:}" "${SHELLSPEC_AFTER_ALL_1%%:*}"'
   ++ set -- AFTER_ALL 'teardown_environment || fail "Teardown failed"' 1#105
   + SHELLSPEC_HOOK_BLOCK_NO=1
   + SHELLSPEC_HOOK_LINENO=105
   + case $1 in
   + '[' 1 = 1 ']'
   + shellspec_is_marked_group 1
   + eval '[ "$SHELLSPEC_MARK_1" ] &&:'
   ++ '[' 1 ']'
   ++ :
   + :
   + eval 'SHELLSPEC_HOOK=$2 && teardown_environment || fail "Teardown failed" &&:'
   ++ SHELLSPEC_HOOK='teardown_environment || fail "Teardown failed"'
   ++ teardown_environment
   ++ echo 'Tearing down environment...'
   ++ rm -rf C:/extract-delta-console-log-1725509273 C:/minimized-checkout-root-1725509273 C://checkout-root-1725509273 C:/extracted-delta-root-1725509273
   ++ :
   + :
   + SHELLSPEC_HOOK_STATUS=0
   + return 0

   + return 0

I had added debug logs but could not find any additional errors. SHELLSPEC_HOOK_STATUS=0 could me found in the logs which suppose to mean no error has occurred. But none of my tests are getting executed as well.
The shell spec version I am using is as follows

$ shellspec -v
0.28.1

Above script is executed in a windows OS and I am checking for the compatibility of OS as well.
   # Determine OS type
    OS_TYPE=$(uname 2>/dev/null || echo "Unknown")

    case "$OS_TYPE" in
        Darwin|Linux)
            TMP_DIR="/tmp"
            ;;
        CYGWIN*|MINGW*|MSYS*)
            if command -v cygpath >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                TMP_DIR="$(cygpath -m "${TEMP:-/tmp}")"
            else
                echo "Error: cygpath not found" >&2
                exit 1
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Error: Unsupported OS: $OS_TYPE" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac


Bad usage of temp directory, because the directory is not thread save. Better is to use TMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d) || exit 1.  || exit 1 stops the script on error (e.g. if creating fails).  Use rm -rf "$TMP_DIR" to remove the directory.

... and if that is done per test then it removes the need for that date-based TEST_ID stuff, which also is not thread- or multiprocessing-safe.
